# The institute has considerable influence with teachers

Tags: meaning

I'd like to ask which interpretation is correct?

> The institute has considerable influence **with** teachers.

a.The institute has influence over teachers.

b.Teachers has influence over the institute.

c.Teachers make the institute capable to exert influence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choice a. "Influence with" and "influence over" mean the same thing.

Comment: Thanks.How can I say the option c.  "The institute has considerable influence by teachers"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say with that one. If you mean that teachers influence the institute, you can say, "Teachers have considerable influence over the institute", or "The institute is influenced by teachers". "... is considerably influenced by ..." is grammatically correct but sounds a little awkward to me.

Comment: If I change the sentence a bit , I mean  , "The institute has influence over education policy of the state . Because many noteworthy scientist are member of it."  I asked if we can say it in one sentence?

Comment: Drop the period and make it one sentence. "The institute has influence over the education policy of the state because many noteworthy scientists are members of it." Note you need an article like "the" in front of "education policy" because it's singular, and "members" should be plural.

Comment: I mean if we can write it using prepositions as "with" or "by". Thank you

Comment: "... has influence by teachers" is not correct. You can "have influence with teachers" or "have influence over teachers", and you can "be influenced by teachers". But you cannot "have influence by teachers". Perhaps I should not that you can "have influence by" an action, like  "have influence by convincing teachers to use their textbooks" or "have influence by paying bribes". But I don't think that's what you want to say.